# Flutter tabbar edge padding

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to create rounded tabs that are scrollable. One issue I an struggling with is, when the first or the last tab selected, there is no padding from the edge of the screen. What can I do to add that padding?

[image: Tabs screen shot]

If I add padding to the Tabbar, the tabs are clipped from the edges like this (see the left most tab):

[image: Clipped tabs]

So was wondering if there is way to make sure that the first and last tab have some padding but once I start scrolling the tabs, they go all the way to the side edges.

For reference, here is my code (with padding added):

```
body: SafeArea(
    child: DefaultTabController(
      length: 6,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            height: 60,
            color: Colors.white,
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, bottom: 20, right: 10),
            child: TabBar(
              isScrollable: true,
              unselectedLabelColor: Colors.black,
              indicator: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
              tabs: [
                Tab(
                  child: Container(
                    height: 40,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                        border: Border.all(color: Colors.black, width: 1)),
                    child: Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        child: Text('Overall')),
                  ),
                ),
                Tab(
                  child: Container(
                    height: 40,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                        border: Border.all(color: Colors.black, width: 1)),
                    child: Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        child: Text('Level-1')),
                  ),
                ),
                Tab(
                  child: Container(
                    height: 40,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                        border: Border.all(color: Colors.black, width: 1)),
                    child: Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        child: Text('Level-2')),
                  ),
                ),
                Tab(
                  child: Container(
                    height: 40,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                        border: Border.all(color: Colors.black, width: 1)),
                    child: Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        child: Text('Level-3')),
                  ),
                ),
                Tab(
                  child: Container(
                    height: 40,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                        border: Border.all(color: Colors.black, width: 1)),
                    child: Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        child: Text('Level-4')),
                  ),
                ),
                Tab(
                  child: Container(
                    height: 40,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                        border: Border.all(color: Colors.black, width: 1)),
                    child: Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        child: Text('Level-5')),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),

          Container(
            //child: Container(
            height: 200,
            //color: Colors.blue,
            child: TabBarView(
              children: [
                Text('One'),
                Text('Two'),
                Text('Three'),
                Text('Four'),
                Text('Five'),
                Text('Six'),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          //),
          //Container(),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.
In case anyone is interested, I added:

```
indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.label,
```